# Trying to get rid of the "cfloop" by writing the correct SQL query

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfml

I am learning to write SQL queries on ColdFusion and now I am faced with the task of getting rid of the loop. This code was originally:

```
<cftransaction>
    <cfloop list="#dogs_id_list#" item="dog_id">
        <cfquery name="qCheck" datasource="#request.DS#">
            SELECT 1
            FROM doghouses dh
            WHERE dh.dog_id = <cfqueryparam value="#dog_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            AND dh.doghouse_id = <cfqueryparam value="#doghouse_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        </cfquery>

        <cfif qCheck.recordCount EQ 0>

        <cfquery name="qIns" datasource="#request.DS#">
            insert into doghouses (
                doghouse_id,
                dog_id
            ) values (
                <cfqueryparam value="#doghouse_id#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_integer">,
                <cfqueryparam value="#dog_id#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_integer">
            )
            <cf_identity_return id="doghouses_id">
        </cfquery>
        <cfset doghouses_id=qIns.id/>
      </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cftransaction>
```

And that's how I tried to shorten it:

```
<cftransaction>
    <cfquery name="qIns" datasource="#request.DS#">
        INSERT INTO doghouses (
            doghouse_id,
            dog_id
        )
        SELECT dh.doghouse_id, dog_id
        FROM doghouses dh
        WHERE dh.doghouse_id = <cfqueryparam value="#doghouse_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            AND dog_id IN (<cfqueryparam value="#dogs_id_list#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">)
        <cf_identity_return id="doghouses_id">
    </cfquery>
    <cfif qIns.recordCount NEQ 0>
        <cfset doghouses_id=qIns.id/>
    </cfif>
</cftransaction>
```

As a result, nothing interferes with the program, but the request returns an empty value and the list of objects is not updated.

> In order to protect the information, the names of the variables have been changed

Please help me figure out where I made a mistake

Comment: It looks like you want an sql `OUTPUT inserted.*` or similar statement

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you are attempting to insert duplicate records into the doghouses table.

Comment: @DanBracuk makes a good point. Rather than an INSERT, a MERGE should be used. An OUTPUT can still be used with the MERGE

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so the code logic in the shorten version is similar to the original code. It's completely different. Let's break this down ( as how I see it):

** in the original code you are doing this:

1. Check if there are any records that have the passed dog id and the doghouse id.
2. If there are no records, then insert a new record in the doghouses table with
   the passed dog id and the doghouse id.

** in your shorten code you're doing this:

1. Insert records in the doghouses table from a SQL query where it should return matching records for the passed dog id and the doghouse id.
2. Then return a list of the matching doghouses id.

The shorten version is more of inserting duplicates in the database.

The correct logic would be to have a query right before the insert statement to check if there any records that matches the passed dog id and the doghouse id, if there are none, then insert a new record.

Keep in mind, that you could do this logic using a stored procedure (which i generally prefer to do that in my own projects) or to use a similar code like in the original code.

One more thing, the transactional database should not contain a select statement. A transaction should be used when you need a set of changes to be processed completely to consider the operation complete and valid. In other words, if only a portion executes successfully, will that result in incomplete or invalid data being stored in your database?

For example, if you have an insert followed by an update, what happens if the insert succeeds and the update fails? If that would result in incomplete data (in this case, an orphaned record), you should wrap the two statements in a transaction to get them to complete as a "set".

Below is how your code should be ( in my opinion):

```
 <cfloop list="#dogs_id_list#" item="dog_id">
 <cfquery name="qCheck" datasource="#request.DS#">
        SELECT 1
        FROM doghouses dh
        WHERE dh.dog_id = <cfqueryparam value="#dog_id#" 
        cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        AND dh.doghouse_id = <cfqueryparam value="#doghouse_id#" 
       cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
       </cfquery>

       <cfif qCheck.recordCount EQ 0>

        <cftransaction>

        <cfquery name="qIns" datasource="#request.DS#">
            insert into doghouses (
                doghouse_id,
                dog_id
            ) values (
                <cfqueryparam value="#doghouse_id#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_integer">,
                <cfqueryparam value="#dog_id#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_integer">
            )
            <cf_identity_return id="doghouses_id">
        </cfquery>
        <cfset doghouses_id=qIns.id/>
 

</cftransaction>

</cfif>

</cfloop>
```